# node.js: wait until all threads are done

Tags: node.js, multithreading, coffeescript, hubot, slack-api

I'm writing a hubot script in coffeescript. The script opens three threads which all do a YQL query. If each thread sends his message to the chat client (Slack in my case) the [client dies](https://github.com/slackhq/hubot-slack/issues/135). Now I need to somehow gather the strings from all the threads and combine them in one single send command, how do I best do that?

```
slack_message = '*Todays menu*'
for i in [1..3]
  query = "select * from html where url='XPATH.. ["+i+"] XPATH.."
  new YQL.exec query, (response) ->
    m = response.query.results;
    slack_message += m

msg.send slack_message
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always keep a counter:

```
slack_message = '*Todays menu*'
queries_done = 0

for i in [1..3]
  query = "select * from html where url='XPATH.. ["+i+"] XPATH.."
  new YQL.exec query, (response) ->
    m = response.query.results
    slack_message += m

    if queries_done is 3
      msg.send slack_message
```

You could also use [Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/):

```
Promise = require("promise")

call_query = (query) ->
  new Promise (resolve) ->
    new YQL.exec query, (response) ->
      resolve response.query.results;

get_menu = ->
  slack_message = '*Todays menu*'
  queries = []
  for i in [1..3]
    queries.push (call_query "select * from html where url='XPATH.. ["+i+"] XPATH..")

  Promise.all(queries).then (messages) ->
    msg.send slack_message + messages.join()
```

Promises are an alternative to callbacks for asynchronous logic and you can do nifty things with them like `Promise.all`, which is just what you're looking for. It takes in an array of `Promise` objects and when they are all resolved it goes on to execute the `.then`. If you've got an evening I suggest reading a bit about them. They can make things nicer once you get a hang of how they work.

Comment: thanks, promises was exactly what I was looking for, I ended up using this. Can you alter your answer and add `Promise    = require("promise")` to the start and change `promises.push` into `queries.push`? This was missing for me to make it work

Comment: oops! edited the variable name but apparently I missed one ha. Glad you found them useful!